# How to write a Maven plugin that calls exec:java and doesn't interfere with the user's classpath?

Tags: java, scala, maven, plugins

I would like to create a maven plugin for my project before I open source it.

The project attaches a Java agent to the start of running an application, to instrument it for various types of profiling. The agent writes out text files for later processing.

I would like to be able to write a maven plugin that can:

- have an alternative to `exec:java` which launches a new java process, with the agent added to the argument list, and passing all the users commands.
- on exit, I then want to invoke some arbitrary post-processing code to produce an HTML report

I have written [Maven plugins before](https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java/tree/master/generator), so I am reasonably familiar with the API, but I don't know how to extend `exec:java` without rewriting it.

**How would I define a new target that can invoke `exec:java`, respecting the user's argument list - but ensuring that it runs forked and with my agent attached - and then giving control back to my plugin to run some post-processing?**

I should also note that my plugin (the post processing part) is written in Scala... how do I make sure that my own extensive dependency list will not interfere with the user's build? (e.g. I might use a different version of Scala than the user wants)

Comment: What about providing patches to exec-maven-plugin ?

Comment: @khmarbaise you really think that would be necessary?

Comment: I didn't said it would be necessary but it might be good improvement for the exec-maven-plugin to support things like `exec:start` or `exec:stop` ? Or `exec:java-start`, `exec:java-stop`...

Comment: Did you ever come to a conclusion to this issue? Am facing the same issue and would be interested to know how you resolved it?